# How do use VBA to reference a call by the heading of the column rather than the location of the cell in the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a Master excel sheet where each row is an item and each item has many properties in the columns of the sheet.
I also have a template excel sheet with the same property fields as the master but in a different more aesthetically pleasing format.
Using VBA I want to copy the template and then fill out the template for each row of the master sheet based on the properties of the master row.

I had this working well using the code below:

```vb
Sub Create_Vlv_DiaphragmBlck()
    Dim rng As Range, rngLoop As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Row As Integer, ItmNum As Integer, PgNum As Integer, DSCount As Integer

    If Not SheetExists_Vlv_DiaphragmBlck("Template") Then
        MsgBox "The Template sheet does not exist. Make sure the Template is included before processing.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
        Set rng = .Range("E3", "E" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        Row = 2
        ItmNum = 1
        PgNum = 6
        DSCount = 1
        For Each rngLoop In rng
            If Not SheetExists_Vlv_DiaphragmBlck(rngLoop.Value) Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                Set ws = ActiveSheet
                ws.Name = rngLoop.Value
            Else
                Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(rngLoop.Value)
            End If
            'Adding tag numbers to Tag List
            
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("D" & Row).Value = rngLoop.Value
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("F" & Row).Value = .Range("M" & rngLoop.Row).Value
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("A" & Row).Value = .Range("CS" & rngLoop.Row).Value
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("C" & Row).Value = ItmNum
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("H" & Row).Value = PgNum
            Row = Row + 1
            ItmNum = ItmNum + 1
            PgNum = PgNum + 1
            
            
            'Datasheets
            If DSCount = 1 Then
            ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "4. Instrument Data Sheets"
            End If
            
            
            'Header
            ws.Range("L1").Value = .Range("A" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Document Number
            ws.Range("L2").Value = .Range("B" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Client
            ws.Range("L3").Value = .Range("C" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Project
            ws.Range("L4").Value = .Range("D" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Location
            'General
            ws.Range("I5").Value = .Range("E" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Tag Number
            ws.Range("L5").Value = .Range("F" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Assembly No.
            ws.Range("I6").Value = .Range("G" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Tag Status
            ws.Range("I7").Value = .Range("H" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Area Class
            ws.Range("L7").Value = .Range("I" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Enclosure Class
            ws.Range("I8").Value = .Range("J" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'P&ID Drawing Number
            ws.Range("I9").Value = .Range("K" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Line/Equipment Number
            ws.Range("I10").Value = .Range("L" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Description
            ws.Range("I11").Value = .Range("M" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Instrument Type
            ws.Range("I12").Value = .Range("N" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Manufacturer
            ws.Range("E13").Value = .Range("O" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Model
            'Process
            ws.Range("I14").Value = .Range("P" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Fluid
            ws.Range("I15").Value = .Range("Q" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Fluid state
            ws.Range("I16").Value = .Range("R" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Temp Min
            ws.Range("L16").Value = .Range("S" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Temp Max
            ws.Range("I17").Value = .Range("T" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Pressure Min
            ws.Range("L17").Value = .Range("U" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Pressure Max
            ws.Range("I18").Value = .Range("V" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Max Design Pressure Upstream
            ws.Range("I19").Value = .Range("W" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Max Design Pressure Downstream
            ws.Range("I20").Value = .Range("X" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Maximum Shutoff Pressure
            ws.Range("I21").Value = .Range("Y" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Valve Size
            'Body
            ws.Range("I22").Value = .Range("Z" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Body Design
            ws.Range("I23").Value = .Range("AA" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Line Size
            ws.Range("K23").Value = .Range("AB" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Schedule
            ws.Range("M23").Value = .Range("AC" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Pipe Material
            ws.Range("I24").Value = .Range("AD" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Conn1 Size
            ws.Range("L24").Value = .Range("AE" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Type
            ws.Range("I25").Value = .Range("AF" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Conn2 Size
            ws.Range("L25").Value = .Range("AG" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Type
            ws.Range("I26").Value = .Range("AH" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Conn3 Size
            ws.Range("L26").Value = .Range("AI" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Type
            ws.Range("I27").Value = .Range("AJ" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Conn4 Size
            ws.Range("L27").Value = .Range("AK" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Type
            ws.Range("I28").Value = .Range("AL" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Conn5 Size
            ws.Range("L28").Value = .Range("AM" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Type
            ws.Range("I29").Value = .Range("AN" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Material Body
            ws.Range("I30").Value = .Range("AO" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Material Seat
            ws.Range("L30").Value = .Range("AP" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Seal
            ws.Range("I31").Value = .Range("AQ" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Material Trim
            ws.Range("L31").Value = .Range("AR" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Diaphragm
            ws.Range("I32").Value = .Range("AS" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Bonnet Type
            ws.Range("L32").Value = .Range("AT" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Material
            ws.Range("I33").Value = .Range("AU" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Wetted Parts Finish
            ws.Range("L33").Value = .Range("AV" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Ext. Finish
            ws.Range("I34").Value = .Range("AW" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Leakage Class
            ws.Range("I35").Value = .Range("AX" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Pressure Rating
            ws.Range("I36").Value = .Range("AY" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Temperature Rating
            ws.Range("I37").Value = .Range("AZ" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Valve Configuration
            ws.Range("L37").Value = .Range("BA" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Conf. Dwg. No.
            ws.Range("I38").Value = .Range("BB" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Max Allowable Sound Level
            'Actuator
            ws.Range("I39").Value = .Range("BC" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Actuator Type
            ws.Range("L39").Value = .Range("BD" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Size
            ws.Range("I40").Value = .Range("BE" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Material
            ws.Range("L40").Value = .Range("BF" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Motive Power
            ws.Range("I41").Value = .Range("BG" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Failure Mode
            ws.Range("I42").Value = .Range("BH" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Stroke
            ws.Range("I43").Value = .Range("BI" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Position Indicator
            ws.Range("I44").Value = .Range("BJ" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Inst. Air Operating Pressure
            ws.Range("I45").Value = .Range("BK" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Act. Air Pressure Min
            ws.Range("L45").Value = .Range("BL" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Act. Air Pressure Max
            'Limit Switches / Solenoid Valve
            ws.Range("I46").Value = .Range("BM" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Limit Sw Tag: Open
            ws.Range("L46").Value = .Range("BN" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Limit Sw Tag: Closed
            ws.Range("I47").Value = .Range("BO" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Solenoid Tag
            ws.Range("I48").Value = .Range("BP" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Limit Sw Manufacturer
            ws.Range("L48").Value = .Range("BQ" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Model
            ws.Range("I49").Value = .Range("BR" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Limit Sw Type
            ws.Range("L49").Value = .Range("BS" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Form
            ws.Range("I50").Value = .Range("BT" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Limit Sw Quantity
            ws.Range("L50").Value = .Range("BU" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Load
            ws.Range("I51").Value = .Range("BV" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Housing Material
            ws.Range("L51").Value = .Range("BW" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'O-Ring Material
            ws.Range("I52").Value = .Range("BX" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Solenoid Type
            ws.Range("L52").Value = .Range("BY" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'SOL LOC / REM
            ws.Range("I53").Value = .Range("BZ" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'SOL Manufacturer
            ws.Range("L53").Value = .Range("CA" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Model
            ws.Range("I54").Value = .Range("CB" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Tube Material
            ws.Range("I55").Value = .Range("CC" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Solenoid Signal Type
            ws.Range("I56").Value = .Range("CD" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Electrial Connection
            'Options
            ws.Range("I57").Value = .Range("CE" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Adj. Mech. Stroke Limiter
            ws.Range("I58").Value = .Range("CF" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Cleaning Requirements
            ws.Range("I59").Value = .Range("CG" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Tagging Requirements
            ws.Range("I60").Value = .Range("CH" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Exhaust Air Muffler
            'Notes
            ws.Range("C61").Value = .Range("CI" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Note 1
            ws.Range("C62").Value = .Range("CJ" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Note 2
            ws.Range("C63").Value = .Range("CK" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Note 3
            ws.Range("C64").Value = .Range("CL" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Note 4
            ws.Range("C65").Value = .Range("CM" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Note 5
            ws.Range("C66").Value = .Range("CN" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Note 6
            ws.Range("C67").Value = .Range("CO" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Note 7
            ws.Range("C68").Value = .Range("CP" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Note 8
            'Revision Detail
            ws.Range("E70").Value = .Range("CQ" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Document Rev
            ws.Range("E71").Value = .Range("CR" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Document Rev Date
            ws.Range("E72").Value = .Range("CS" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Tag Rev
            ws.Range("E73").Value = .Range("CT" & rngLoop.Row).Value 'Tag Rev Date
            
            DSCount = DSCount + 1
            
            
            
            
        Next
        .Activate
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My problem is, that now I want to match the Master column with the template column based on its name rather than its position in the master sheet and template.
This is the code I have now but it isn't working:

```vb
Sub Create_Vlv_DiaphragmBlck()
    Dim rng As Range, columrng As Range, rngLoop As Range, columrngLoop As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Row As Integer, ItmNum As Integer, PgNum As Integer, DSCount As Integer
    Dim mastertarget, templatetarget
    Dim temprow As Integer, tempcolum As Integer

    If Not SheetExists_Vlv_DiaphragmBlck("Template") Then
        MsgBox "The Template sheet does not exist. Make sure the Template is included before processing.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
        Set rng = .Range("E3", "E" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        Set columrng = .Range("A2", .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        Row = 2
        ItmNum = 1
        PgNum = 6
        DSCount = 1
        For Each rngLoop In rng
            If Not SheetExists_Vlv_DiaphragmBlck(rngLoop.Value) Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
                Set ws = ActiveSheet
                ws.Name = rngLoop.Value
            Else
                Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(rngLoop.Value)
            End If
            'Adding tag numbers to Tag List
            
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("D" & Row).Value = rngLoop.Value
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("F" & Row).Value = .Range("M" & rngLoop.Row).Value
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("A" & Row).Value = .Range("CS" & rngLoop.Row).Value
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("C" & Row).Value = ItmNum
            Sheets("Tag List").Range("H" & Row).Value = PgNum
            Row = Row + 1
            ItmNum = ItmNum + 1
            PgNum = PgNum + 1
            
            
            'Datasheets
            If DSCount = 1 Then
            ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "4. Instrument Data Sheets"
            End If
            
            For Each columrngLoop In columrng
            mastertarget = .Range(columrngLoop.Column & "1").Value
            For temprow = 1 To 10
                For tempcolum = 1 To 10
                    templatetarget = Sheets("Template").Cells(temprow, tempcolum)
                    If mastertarget = templatetarget Then
                    ws.Cells(temprow, tempcolum + 6).Value = .Range(columrngLoop.Column & rngLoop.Row).Value
                    End If
                    Next tempcolum
            Next temprow
            Next columrngLoop
            DSCount = DSCount + 1
            
            
            
            
        Next rngLoop
        .Activate
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Screenshot of the partial master sheet:
[image]

Screenshot of the partial template sheet:
[image]

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a very useful description of the problem you're having with your modified code - what is it doing or not doing which is different from what you want it to do?

Comment: `columrngLoop.Column` returns a numeric value, not a column letter.  If you want to refer to a cell based on row and column numbers, use (eg) `Cells(1, columrngLoop.Column)`

Comment: I get an error 2Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim. I fixed that but I'm still getting the error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: On which line though?

Comment: `Set columrng = .Range("A2", .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)` this looks off.  This would give you (eg) ` .Range("A2", 15)` if you had the last occupied column in row 3 being 15   Where are your headers? Only in Row 2?

Comment: Might be useful to add a screenshot of your Master and Template (at least the parts of those sheets which contain the headers)

Comment: All the headings of the master sheet are in row 2. The corresponding headings in the template are in random rows and columns. I've added screenshots to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to try - see comments inline.  I see some repeated headers in your template screenshot though -eg "Max" x 2 and "Type" x 2, so that's not going to work well

```vb
Sub Create_Vlv_DiaphragmBlck()
    
    Dim rng As Range, columrng As Range, rngLoop As Range, columrngLoop As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Row As Long, ItmNum As Long, PgNum As Long, DSCount As Long '<< prefer Long over Integer
    Dim mastertarget, templatetarget
    Dim temprow As Long, tempcolum As Long
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet, wsMaster As Worksheet, wsTags As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, id As String
    
    If Not SheetExists_Vlv_DiaphragmBlck("Template") Then
        MsgBox "The Template sheet does not exist. Make sure the Template is included before processing.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<< better to set this once then just use `wb`
    Set wsTemplate = wb.Worksheets("Template")
    Set wsMaster = wb.Worksheets("Master")
    Set wsTags = wb.Worksheets("Tag List")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsMaster
        
        Set rng = .Range("E3", "E" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row). _
                      SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        Set columrng = .Range("A2", .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)). _
                      SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        
        Row = 2
        ItmNum = 1
        PgNum = 6
        DSCount = 1
        
        For Each rngLoop In rng.Cells
        
            id = rngLoop.Value '<< just read this once...
            Set ws = GetWorksheet(wb, id, True, wsTemplate) '<< factored out to a separate function
            
            'Adding tag numbers to Tag List
            With wsTags.Rows(Row)
                .Columns("D").Value = id
                .Columns("F").Value = .Range("M" & rngLoop.Row).Value
                .Columns("A").Value = .Range("CS" & rngLoop.Row).Value
                .Columns("C").Value = ItmNum
                .Columns("H").Value = PgNum
            End With
            Row = Row + 1
            ItmNum = ItmNum + 1
            PgNum = PgNum + 1
            
            'Datasheets
            If DSCount = 1 Then ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "4. Instrument Data Sheets"
            
            For Each columrngLoop In columrng
                'Use Find to locate a matching value
                Set f = ws.Range("A1:N200").Find(what:=columrngLoop.Value, _
                          lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
                
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    SetValueCell f, _
                          rngLoop.EntireRow.Cells(columrngLoop.Column).Value
                Else
                    '? no match - need to flag this ?
                    rngLoop.EntireRow.Cells(columrngLoop.Column).Font.Color = vbRed
                End If
            Next columrngLoop
            DSCount = DSCount + 1
        Next rngLoop
        .Activate
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'given a header/label cell, determine where its corresponding value cell is
Function SetValueCell(headerCell As Range, v)
    Dim cols As Long
    'how many columns are merged?
    Select Case headerCell.MergeArea.Columns.Count
        Case 1: cols = 1
        Case 3: cols = 4
        Case 6: cols = 7 'you said 1 but ?
        Case Else: cols = 1
    End Select
    headerCell.Offset(0, cols).Value = v 'put value at correct offset
End Function

'Look for sheet `wsName` in workbook `wb` - if not found and `bCreateIfMissing` is True,
'  then add a sheet with that name to the end of the workbook, optionally using
'  a template worksheet `wsTemplate`
Function GetWorksheet(wb As Workbook, wsName As String, _
               Optional bCreateIfMissing As Boolean = False, _
               Optional wsTemplate As Worksheet = Nothing) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if missing
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    If ws Is Nothing And bCreateIfMissing Then
        If Not wsTemplate Is Nothing Then
            wsTemplate.Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        Else
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
        End If
        ws.Name = wsName 'set the name (no error handling here...)
    End If
    Set GetWorksheet = ws 'return a sheet or Nothing if sheet is not to be created
End Function
```

If you just want an easy way to map your "Master" columns to specific cells in the template sheet, you can consider adding a row above your Master sheet headers, and placing the cell address for each mapped cell on the template sheet in that new row.  Then you can loop over those values and place the data without needing to do any searching (and you don't need to worry about having similar/duplicate headers on the template sheet)

Comment: Tim, thank you so much for the above. The find method is working well. However, there is still a problem. The offset method works differently depnsing on the size of teh merged cell in the template. For example, if the merged cell spans 3 cells, then the offset value should be (0,4).  However, if the merged cell spans 6 cells then the correct offset is (0,1). Do you suggest anyway to address this issue?

Comment: Added a new method in the code, to figure out where the value goes according to how many columns are in the merged cell area.

Comment: @JohnND21 Avoid merged cells like the plague. Use 'center across selection" instead, wherever you can.